# Calling the camera from another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I have my main Activity in which I have a few Buttons.
One of them is supposed to open the Camera.
To make it cleaner I am using `View.onClick()`, so I will just have the Button on the main Activity and the rest will be managed by another other class (Camactivity).

In my main Activity :

```
  Button btnrep = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
  btnrep.setOnClickListener(new Camactivity(this));
```

and in my

```
public class Camactivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener

    private File imageFile;
    private Context appContext;

    public MainActivity_1(Context context)
    {
        appContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);//use intent and pass in mediastore
                //mediastore is a databases where image and video are stores and link

                imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "BreedingGround.bmp");
        /*link to a directory - pass in directory where you want to save the pictures and names of the file*/


                Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);//Convert imageFile to a Uri
                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempuri);//location where u want the image file to be save after taking photo
                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);//quality of out image, 1 means high quality image


                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);//Request code 0 to identify who send the request

    }
```

However I am getting a null pointer error at `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.mohit.softeng, PID: 22075
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:97)
      at com.example.mohit.softeng.MainActivity_1.onClick(MainActivity_1.java:60)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: 1) Never `new` an Activity class. 2) Activity class should not have constructors. 3) You do not need to pass a Context to an Activity since `Activity extends Context`

Comment: For the 2 and 3 suggestion i am able to edit however for the ( new ) i am unable to remove as if i just put my activity name in  btnrep.setOnClickListener(Camactivity()); i am receiving an error to which only suggestion is to put new

Comment: You don't need a separate activity - that was my main point. Plus, never "construct" an Activity outside of `startActivity` was my other point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are more than welcome to define a `View.OnClickListener` subclass, but 
there's really no reason I see to have `Camactivity` at all, so just implement `View.OnClickListener` onto `MainActivity`.

Besides, you will likely want the result from `startActivityForResult` within `MainActivity`'s `onActivityResult`, not `Camactivity`.

So, with that suggestion

```
Button btnrep = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
btnrep.setOnClickListener(this);
```

If you already have your Activity implementing an `OnClickListener`, then add an if-statement to check which button is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button3:
            openCamera();
    }
}

private void openCamera() {
    // That other code in Camactivity
}
```

---

---

Alternative answer... still not using `new` to make an Activity class.

```
Button btnrep = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
btnrep.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cam = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Camactivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(cam, 0); // If you need the result in MainAcivity, pass it back from camActivity
        // else, just startActivity(cam);
    }
});
```

Then, update `Camactivity` to start the camera intent as soon as it is created.

```
public class Camactivity extends Activity {

    private File imageFile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);//use intent and pass in mediastore
        //mediastore is a databases where image and video are stores and link

        imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "BreedingGround.bmp");
/*link to a directory - pass in directory where you want to save the pictures and names of the file*/

        Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);//Convert imageFile to a Uri
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempuri);//location where u want the image file to be save after taking photo
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);//quality of out image, 1 means high quality image

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);//Request code 0 to identify who send the request

    } 

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            // TODO: Handle camera intent result
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: i am able to run the application if i have everything under main activity , as per you suggested, however i have to separate the UI(button) and the logic(Camactivity) therefore i am trying to do it this way

Comment: Okay... not sure who is enforcing that requirement on you. I'll edit, but I don't like the solution.

Comment: Sorry about the trouble !! but apparently it makes whole application flow more "visible" so we have to follow.

Comment: Sorry there are no errors after following the alternative answer but upon clicking the button it is just showing a white screen thats all.

Comment: Well, it doesn't need `setContentView`, so yeah, it'll be a blank activity. It should, however, start the camera intent as soon as the activity starts.

Comment: Oh sorry about that it was an error on my side. thank you very much for your help. the camera works!